# Kali Linux: Broken Java

Tags: java, linux, jar

Java stopped working in kali linux. When I run the jar file I get the exception. For example, exception from CobaltStrike. I have it on 2.5, 3.6 and 3.8 versions.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/swing/plaf/synth/SynthIcon
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1009)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:801)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:699)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:622)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:580)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1009)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:801)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:699)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:622)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:580)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:374)
at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.finder.ClassFinder.findClass(ClassFinder.java:103)
at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.finder.ClassFinder.resolveClass(ClassFinder.java:171)
at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.decoder.DocumentHandler.findClass(DocumentHandler.java:406)
at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.decoder.NewElementHandler.addAttribute(NewElementHandler.java:80)
at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.decoder.ObjectElementHandler.addAttribute(ObjectElementHandler.java:102)
at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.decoder.DocumentHandler.startElement(DocumentHandler.java:296)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthParser.startElement(SynthParser.java:1227)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:394)
at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:197)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthParser.parse(SynthParser.java:242)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.load(SynthLookAndFeel.java:579)
at de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaLookAndFeel.loadXMLConfig(SyntheticaLookAndFeel.java:401)
at de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaLookAndFeel.<init>(SyntheticaLookAndFeel.java:339)
at de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaBlueIceLookAndFeel.<init>(SyntheticaBlueIceLookAndFeel.java:31)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:560)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:632)
at aggressor.ui.UseSynthetica.setup(UseSynthetica.java:29)
at aggressor.Aggressor.main(Aggressor.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.swing.plaf.synth.SynthIcon
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 52 more
```

I have openjdk-9-jdk and jre installed with headless versions. So i have openjdk-8-jre, how i can run jars throught 8 jre? Any help?
I have purged and reinstalled java, but no solution was found(
Previously, everything was run without problems

Comment: `I have openjdk-9-jdk and jre installed with headless versions`, this seems to be the problem. You are still running headless (without swing). `So i have openjdk-8-jre`, you have it "installed" or "unzipped" anywhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

This helped me! I was changed java version to 8 and all works fine)